# Пропадает wifi linux mint cinnamon 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, linux-mint, asus

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема. Установил Linux mint cinnamon 18. Ноутбук модели asus x556ua. Пропадает wifi когда просто что-то делаю на ноутбуке и при обновлениях или уставновке пакетов. Менял на другие дистрибутивы - не помогает. На Windows все хорошо работает.
Знает ли кто-то в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: для начала нужно посмотреть в консоли вывод dmesg и понять, что там происходит. Потом, посмотерть вывод lsusb/lspci, что бы понять, какой там wifi адаптер.

Comment: Может проблема в драйвере самом. Модель адаптера напишите, пожалуйста

Comment: dmesg
 `AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
[21332.844744] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
[21332.844746] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[21332.844748] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
[21332.844752] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
[21332.845100] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5`

Comment: lsusb
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: @Chubatiy, Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04 и http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=245386.0. Читайте/пробуйте

Answer (score 1):

Помогла эта команда

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```